# Typed Dataset & UnTyped DataSet

Tags: sql-server, database, vb.net

I am very new in VB.Net and SQL, I have designed a Database in SQL for a simple Payroll application, now at the stage of programing interface in VB.Net, I have done a form with UnTyped DataSet and pulled the data as a test and its working fine. now I feel a bit ease while using Typed DataSet where it is much easier to drop tables and columns which will work automatically for related data as well but my question is that :
once I finish this interface the database will be kept in our company SQL Server and the interface will be used at different sites/country so if I use Strongly Typed DataSet and develop interface and compile and deploy to other computers how I will be able to change the data source because during design time the database is in my computer and after deployment the interface should communicate with Database located in sever. so should I relay on untyped dataset and give a notepad with the application for configuring sql connection settings or is there any other way around ?

one more doubt or I should move the database to sever during the design time and start developing interface with that connection ?

please help me.

Comment: Guys I have found a file named XML Configuration along with the application .exe file , is that one we use to change connection settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use multiple connections using `ODBC`

https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-sql-server-odbc-driver/